# How can I debug this php/MySQL error?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis

On my WordPress site I can't delete any pages, posts, attachments, basically anything in the database.

My first guess was MySQL permissions problem but the MySQL user that WordPress is using has full permissions for that database and I can delete things through phpMyAdmin under the same user.

When I turn on `mysql.trace_mode` in my php.ini I get an error displayed on every page

```
Warning: Unknown: 1 result set(s) not freed. Use mysql_free_result to free result sets which were requested using mysql_query() in Unknown on line 0
```

My WordPress site is running under IIS7.5.

Is there anything IIS specific I should change?

Or, is there any other setting to help me debug this issue?

Comment: The error message is telling you what you need to do - "Use mysql_free_result" so you need to place this command within the area of the file that is processing the data.

Comment: check this: http://www.concrete5.org/developers/bugs/5-6-0-2/warning-unknown-1-result-sets-not-freed.-use-mysql_free_result-t/

Comment: I feel that I shouldn't need to use mysql_free_result on a WordPress site for core functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this error because of plugin de active your plugins and check that again and than one by one active them and trace the plugin which one is giving you this error and replace that plugin

Comment: I fixed this a while ago and that turned out to be the problem